# YARN client authentication fails with SIMPLE authentication is not enabled. Available:[TOKEN]

Tags: spring, authentication, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I've setup a simple local PHD 3.0 Hadoop cluster and followed the steps described in the [Spring Yarn Basic Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic-single/)

Running the app against my Hadoop cluster gives

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
```

and the following stack trace in the YARN ResourceManager:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.initializeAuthContext(Server.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:636)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:607)
```

This is probably a very basic question.
I'd like simply to run a YARN app test without setting up any authentication.

As I understand, YARN does not allow SIMPLE client authentication:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2156

According to this question
[How can I pass a Kerberos ticket to Spring Yarn application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651452/how-can-i-pass-a-kerberos-ticket-to-spring-yarn-application)

I might end up setting up a Kerberos authentication.

Is there a way to run Spring YARN example without elaborate authentication setup?

Comment: Could you add these points : Version of hadoop, value for "hadoop.security.authentication "

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, Hadoop distribution is Pivotal HD 3.0. It is based on Hadoop version 2.6.0 as far as I can tell.

Comment: The hadoop.security.authentication is everywhere set to 'simple'. But that doesn't matter, since it has no effect by design, please see the link to the YARN JIRA ticket in the question.

Comment: After reading the JIRA comments I come to a conclusion radically different: the YARN services *require* a token, and that token has to be created **before** contacting the services (quote  "Yarn uses tokens regardless of your security setting"). When security model is SIMPLE, you just assert that you are user XYZ and voila, you've got a token. That's one of the things Spring should do automagically. But in your case it doesn't work. Tough luck. And with a Kerberized cluster I fear that Spring would fail too.

Comment: I suspected that I need to get a token for a TOKEN authentication. My amateur YARN question is how would I do that. A pointer to a non-Spring way of doing that is very welcome!

Comment: Spring YARN handles all tokens internally, so we can look it further if my answer didn't resolve this question. Might be that with wrong configuration tokens wasn't received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was simple.
I had to add

```
spring:
    hadoop:
        resourceManagerAddress: myyarnhost:8050
        resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: myyarnhost:8030
```

to the `application.yml` too, but mixed up the port numbers (8030 for manager and 8050 for ManagerScheduler). 
And that typo has caused such effect.

Maybe adding these two configuration properties to the getting started guide could save some time to the next readers.

Also, to run the example against a freshly installed PHD3.0 I had to modify the HDFS client user name by exporting the default `HADOOP_USER_NAME`:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that with 5 node phd30 cluster and everything was ok:

In `build.gradle` I used phd30 packages instead of vanilla(which depends on hadoop 2.6.0). Versions in this case should not matter afaik.

```
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-yarn-boot:2.2.0.RELEASE-phd30")
testCompile("org.springframework.data:spring-yarn-boot-test:2.2.0.RELEASE-phd30")
```

In `src/main/resources/application.yml` I changed hdfs, rm and scheduler addresses to match cluster settings:

```
spring:
    hadoop:
        fsUri: hdfs://ambari-2.localdomain:8020
        resourceManagerAddress: ambari-3.localdomain:8050
        resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: ambari-3.localdomain:8030
```

Then I just ran it externally from my own computer:

```
$ java -jar target/gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar
```

There's one `appmaster` and one `container` executed and app should succeed.

If it still doesn't work then there's something else. I didn't deploy `hawk` if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you Janne! I'm thinking may be that has anything to do with simple non-FQDN names of the hosts I'm using in my setup. Will recheck following your comments!